# Troubles transferring data from text box to Firebase and displaying that data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have created two pages, one with a text box to input data that should be stored in Firebase and another that should display that stored data, but i am having issues with some of the data not being stored, and none of the data being displayed on the second page. The HTML for the text box is as follows:

```
    <form>
        <div class="post-title">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Post Title">
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="Post Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

The HTML for the page that should display the data is:

```
    <div class="result">
        <h4 class="postTitle">Paragraph 1</h4>
            <p class="postContent">Welcome to my test blog. This is a paragraph.</p>
            <div class="postDate">
                <p>Date of post: </p>
                <p class="postDate2">date</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript that should transfer data from the text box to my Firebase :

```
    var url = "https://blog-posts.firebaseio.com/";
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);

    function funct1(event)
    {
        var title = $("#post-title").text();
        var post = $("#post-content").text();
        var date = Date();
        firebaseRef.push({Title: title, Content: post, Date: date});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

    submit.onclick = funct1;
```

And the javascript that should retrieve data from my Firebase and display it (Note, both javascript extracts are from the same .js file, i seperated them for readability):

```
    firebaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var message = snapshot.val();
    });

    $("postTitle").replaceWith(title);
    $("postContent").replaceWith(post);
    $("postDate2").replaceWith(date);
```

The Date/Time seems to copy to my Firebase, but if i enter something in either text box and click submit, the data is not stored in my Firebase. Also nothing including the Date/Time is being changed on the page that should display the data.

Comment: Accepted it just now, im new to the site and didnt realise you had the option to accept the answer. Thanks for the help on the last question, I did follow your advice and as you can see from this question the date is working but not the title/content and ive also added some extra stuff which also isnt working (to display the data on another page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be fairly straight forward here.

Update your form HTML to this -

```
<form>
        <div class="post-title">
            <input id="post-title" type="text" placeholder="Post Title">
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <textarea id="post-content" type="text" placeholder="Post Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Where you have the following -

```
    var title = $("#post-title").text();
    var post = $("#post-content").text();
```

change to

```
    var title = $("#post-title").val();
    var post = $("#post-content").val();
```

It looks as though you are new to jquery as well, so you may want to also read [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/) to help you understand how to get values, and work with selectors, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have edited the .text() to .val() and also added an id to each text box (and renamed the class of the divs surrounding them to prevent possible confliction) but im still having the same problem, its only the date that's being transferred to my firebase.

Comment: you may have some other issues going on as well. I'll set up a fiddle to show you how getting these values works. You are a student, right?

Comment: Ok - here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5SyQ/) for you to look at and see how I am grabbing the values.  Break your problem down into smaller chunks.  Right now - just work on getting your values. Then figure out how to get those to firebase.

Comment: Yes and this is part of some work for a basic blog. Im not sure why the date works but not the other two values. I've also tried the following for obtaining the value:

var title = $("#post-titlediv.post-title").val();

Comment: Date works because you are creating it in the function.  It looks like most of it will work, you just need to get the values out of the input boxes.

Comment: I tried commenting out my code and adding your code from the fiddle to see if that worked in capturing the content from the text boxes but to no avail. I also tested it in chrome aswell as firefox.

Comment: the fiddle is just an example - you will have to make it work in your project.

Comment: It seems like some sort of problem with the browser. In JS fiddle i can get it to work (alerts displaying the value) in a couple of different ways, but as soon as i try it in the browser i get no result. (I have saved my code and refreshed the code)